# Rails JSON API mode no longer showing response data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I could test queries in through the browser before and get a JSON response. Now it just shows:

[image]

I have no idea what I changed. My Ember frontend is able to get data fine though.

It's handy to see the response.

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :platforms do
    resources :markets
    member do
      get 'populate_markets'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: And your routes?

Comment: Added routes above.

Comment: What's in the Rails server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the request format in your browser if you want to see the JSON.

Go to `http://localhost:3000/platforms.json`. You'll get whatever `platforms_controller#index` returns as long as it's configured to respond with JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It works with either request now.

Answer (score 0):

God, I figured it out. Localhost is broken. Using the ip address 127.0.0.1 solved the issue. I don't know what I changed since localhost worked before.